# Desktop applications with Meteor.js

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-webkit, electron

The options I've found for creating desktop applications in `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` are:

1. [Electron (formerly Atom-Shell)](https://github.com/atom/electron)
2. [NW.js (formerly Node-Webkit)](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js)

However, there doesn't seem to be any clear implementation for using `meteor.js` with these.

## NW.js

I've seen some other questions of people asking this, but no implementation. Can't even figure out by the answers what I should be trying to put together:

1. [Meteor leaderboard app on node-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441168/meteor-leaderboard-app-on-node-webkit)
2. [Demeteorizer with node-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703867/demeteorizer-with-node-webkit)
3. [How can I start a Meteor instance before launching a node-webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898467/how-can-i-start-a-meteor-instance-before-launching-a-node-webkit)

This guys actually got it running but doesn't say how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508737/iron-router-routing-fails-on-reload-in-node-webkit

The idea proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318856/basic-questions-for-meteorjs) is interesting—loading the desktop application completely from the web. However, I would like to allow my users to use the application offline.

## Electron

There is an actual implementation, [meteor-desktop-app](https://github.com/sigmeus/meteor-desktop-app), but it has no clear support for Windows. However, the `atom-shell` does support Windows just as `NW.js` does.

---

Has anyone figured out an implementation to allow `meteor.js` to operate as a desktop application?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27794917/2104665).

Comment: Thanks. That index.html page may have been the missing piece. All of the NW packages I would create would load "main": "main.js". Will give this a shot shortly.

Comment: That method worked to get Meteor running in NW! Although I'm not looking to keep it entirely offline, will cross that hurdle when I get there. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt did you cross the hurdle yet?

Answer (score 3):

If you drop the code from meteor-desktop-app into [Electron Starter](https://github.com/atom/electron-starter), you'll get Windows + Mac + Linux for free, as well as a build system you can definitely use for Real Apps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mongoclient's scaffold](https://github.com/mongoclient/mongoclient-electron) directory, it'll lead you to your electron app if you follow the steps from readme.