# Is it possible to use meteor code in a desktop application?

Tags: meteor

Can I compile and use meteor code in a desktop application? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

[Atom Shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell)

---

### Long Answer

This can be accomplished using the [Atom Shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell), and they have made a [starter kit](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell-starter) that you can use to help you test the thing out.

Here is the [default Meteor app](https://github.com/sigmeus/meteor-desktop-app) running on Atom, and how it is done is discussed in the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207124/desktop-applications-with-meteor-js).

So, in short, you basically put all your Meteor code in a /meteor folder (see 'default Meteor app' link above) and then run the sucker wrapped in Atom Shell. You can do that by following the [Atom Shell Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md), and if you want an executable app instead of one which you execute from the command line, bundle it up and create your joy following this little ditty on the same topic called [Application Distribution](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-distribution.md).